# check if array of objects includes un object javascript

Tags: javascript

Each formation contains an array of users and I want to check if one user is part of formation's users.
u: the user I want to check if they are part of formation.users.
This is my code

```
 console.log(u)
 console.log(formation.users)
 console.log(formation.users.indexOf(u))
```

Which `u` is object and `formation.users` is array of objects .
This is what i see in the console

```
{ id: 2 }

[ User { id: 2 }, User { id: 3 } ]
```

-1
We see the array includes the object, why do I obtain this result?
Any help please.

Comment: `indexOf` compares using strict equality: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't see that the array includes *the* object, you see that the array includes *an* object with `{ id: 2 }`. Unless it's the exact same object (not some other object that may or may not have the same `id` property as yours), it won't match:

```js
const a = { id: 1 }
const b = { id: 1 }
const c = b

// Now there exist two objects, both with { id: 1 }.
// The first one is assigned to a, and the second
// one is assigned to both b and c. Therefore, b and c
// are equal, but a isn't equal to either of them.

console.log(a === b) // false
console.log(b === c) // true
```

Probably you want to check if it contains *any* object with a matching `id` instead:

```js
console.log(formation.users.some(user => user.id === u.id))
```

(This is based on your question to "check if it's included" - if you actually want the *index*, which is what your existing code suggests that uses `indexOf` and not `includes`, then you'd have to use `findIndex` instead of `some`.)

Answer (score 1):

Each object in javascript is it's own entity. So `let a = {id: 1}` and `let b = {id: 1}` in this example `a` and `b` are different objects. When you try to do the comparison match with `indexOf` it follows strict equality, so because they are different object it does not match them.

To achieve what you want to will need to match on one of the inner properties of `user`.

```
formation.users.findIndex((user) => user.id === u.id)
```